# How to Stream from Twilio to API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, twilio

I've been trying to stream Twilio calls and send them to an API Gateway that is connected to Kinesis. I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
const VoiceResponse = require("twilio").twiml.VoiceResponse;

const response = new VoiceResponse();
const connect = response.connect();
connect.stream({
  url: "ws://apigatewayhost",
});
```

I've watched a couple of videos, and they set up an http server in order to stream. I'm not sure

I tried this snippet from the Twilio Docs

```
const VoiceResponse = require("twilio").twiml.VoiceResponse;

const response = new VoiceResponse();
const connect = response.connect();
connect.stream({
  url: "ws://apigatewayhost",
});
```

I expected that if I passed the API Gateway websocket url, it would send/stream the data to that url. But I didn't get any data reflected on my AWS console. I'm not sure if that is even possible or if they are compatible.

Comment: Stream how? Stream where? To a device? To save in S3? Where is Kinesis hooked up? You can't just connect 2 systems like that together. What's the end goal here?